# Blender 2.82a Cant select through bones

Tags: rigging, bones, selection-tools

In edit mode, with the bones set to wireframe view, I'm simply trying to select one bone, and then shift select another bone, in order to parent one to the other.

The issue, is that the target bone is inside/behind another. and I cant seem to select through it? Each time I go to shift select in inner bone, it selects the larger outer bone.

I believe this should be possible in wireframe mode by selecting the bone outline? But it doesn't seem to be the case?

I can work around it using the outlier, but the issue of selecting bones inside/behind other bones is something I'm looking to solve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bone inside like that is more difficult to select but you can do it two other ways that I know of:

1. Double click on it. Be fast! Mouse cursor right on it, and it works.
2. Select larger bone, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> "Direction", "child" ect and it may also help in certain situations, especially when dealing with multiple parent bones and children.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for those tricks. 

Though, if i shift double click the bone, it adds both the outer and inner bone to my selection, leaving the smaller bone as the active object. This would then lead to both the top and outer bone being parented to the inner bone. Instead of  just the top bone.

I'm new to rigging in blender, but I've been rigging in general for a while. It's is a common technique to have bones laid out like this.  

This was definitely possible in other versions of blender. Can see here: 

[link](https://imgur.com/a/c3G24cE)

Comment: I've just noticed this only seems to affect orthographic view / edit mode. Can select the inner bone through the larger bone ok in perspective view in pose mode... Perhaps a bug?

Comment: Good question. Man I see from the gif it looks so easy and nearly effortless to select the bone inside. It also appears that they were in wire frame view ("Z" key. Shading>Wireframe). *Goes and tries in 2.82a* Yup. It's easier in wire frame mode! How do you like it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and I've just found a way to make it work.

On the Blender *Preferences*, under the *Viewport tab* you'll find a selection dropdown. If you uncheck the *OpenGL Depth Picking* option it should work as you expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I´m having the same problem. What I´m doing as a workaround is first to select the inner bone with double click, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> and drag anywhere in the outer bone. This way the outer bone will be selected and the inner bone will still be the active selection.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be repeatedly working for me in 3.2 is to select the inner bone at this exact location. (The orange marking, not the yellow.)

[image: select-bone-here]